# Date-Picker component not working on a modal in React-js

Tags: reactjs

I am using material-ui date picker component (http://material-ui.com/#/components/date-picker) on a modal in react-js. When I select a particular date in calendar, the page reloads instead of selecting the date. I think the modal events are over riding the date-picker events. I want to over-ride date-picker events over modal events. What is the best solution?
Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: Can you show the code calling the datepicker?

Comment: <DatePicker  {...baseProps} hintText="Choose Date" mode="portrait" className = {"datePicker"}/>
There was a <form> element, in which this date-picker is defined, the form was returning false on any button click( onSubmit ), so date-picker buttons were returning false on click. I made a change to <form> element.

<form className="form" onSubmit={() => false}>

So, this solved my problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
<DatePicker 
  {...baseProps} 
hintText="Choose Date" 
mode="portrait" 
className = {"datePicker"}
/>
```

There was a  element, in which this date-picker is defined, the form was returning false on any button click( onSubmit ), so date-picker buttons were returning false on click. I made a change to  element.

```
<form 
className="form" 
onSubmit={() => false}
>
```

So, this solved my problem.

Comment: Docking this because of the terrible formatting for the answer. Break this up into several lines.